# Undefined appears in the end of the function, how to solve it?

Tags: javascript, function

```
const f = (numero = 6, n1 = 0, n2 = 1) => {
  
for (let i = 1; i <= numero; i++) {
    console.log(n1);
    proximo = n1 + n2;
    n1 = n2;
    n2 = proximo;
}
}
console.log('Sequência de Fibonacci:');
    console.log (f())
```

JAVASCRIPT

It gives me a undefined error, which i dont know how to solve, any help? Thank you in advance!

Comment: It looks like javascript. Can you add the javascript tag ? you need to return a value to print it.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. I already added js tag. How do i return a value?

Comment: `f` doesn't `return` anything…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the `console.log` around your f() call. You are already logging from inside the function:

```js
const f = (numero = 6, n1 = 0, n2 = 1) => {

  for (let i = 1; i <= numero; i++) {
    console.log(n1);
    proximo = n1 + n2;
    n1 = n2;
    n2 = proximo;
  }
}
console.log('Sequência de Fibonacci:');
f()
```

Comment: Thank you very much bro for you attention, have a great week.